# ORDER BY slower on a view rather than a direct SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a view that joins two tables and applies a filter. When I run the view it takes <2s, when I run the same statement as a direct SELECT rather than a view, it also takes <2s.

The confusing part is that if I add an order by when selecting from the view, the query takes >20s, where adding the order by to the query directly takes <2s

My code looks a bit like this:

Creating the view:

```
CREATE VIEW MY_VIEW AS 
SELECT T1.COLUMN1, T2.COLUMN 2
FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2 
WHERE T1.COLUMN3=T2.COLUMN3
```

Querying the view (<2s):

```
SELECT * FROM MY_VIEW
```

Querying directly with no view (<2s)

```
SELECT T1.COLUMN1, T2.COLUMN 2
FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2 
WHERE T1.COLUMN3=T2.COLUMN3
```

Querying the view with an ORDER BY (>20s)

```
SELECT * FROM MY_VIEW ORDER BY COLUMN1
```

Querying the view with an ORDER BY (<2s)

```
SELECT T1.COLUMN1, T2.COLUMN 2
FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2 
WHERE T1.COLUMN3=T2.COLUMN3 
ORDER BY T1.COLUMN1
```

Do you have any advice on how to order by more efficiently on views? Or is the only option to scrap the use of views and stick to direct SELECT.

The plans are the following, respectively (Sorry its images, I found it easier than writing the table in the StackOverflow editor)

[image: SELECT ON THE VIEW]

[image: SELECT ON THE ORIGINAL TABLES DIRECTLY]

[image: SELECT ON THE VIEW WITH ORDER BY]

[image: SELECT ON THE ORIGINAL TABLES DIRECTLY WITH ORDER BY]

Comment: Show us the execution plans.

Comment: Another question, are executing this queries consecutively? I mean you run the view then you run the query outside the view? Because if your answer is yes, you may know that Oracle and others RDBMs cache all or part of a execution plan so the next executions can run faster.

Comment: Thanks Jorge, I tried running them in different orders and the problem persists. However, nice to know about the cache!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Uploaded the explains. Sorry its in image format, I just couldn spend the rest of my life formating the table output onto Stack Overflow editor

Comment: The "table output" can be formatted _very_ easily: Paste it into the SO editor. Select the text. Click on the `{}` button - done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle 11g a view is not actually stored unless you create a materialized view. Therefore what is happening here is that all the `ORDER BY` actions in the plan are executed twice, regardless of the fact that it is the same `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you are facing is that the view definition is compiled.  The execution plan for a query is set when the query is compiled, rather than when it is used.

As you have observed, the best execution plan for:

```
SELECT T1.COLUMN1, T2.COLUMN2
FROM TABLE1 T1 JOIN
     TABLE2 T2 
     ON T1.COLUMN3 = T2.COLUMN3;
```

is different from the best execution plan for:

```
SELECT T1.COLUMN1, T2.COLUMN2
FROM TABLE1 T1 JOIN
     TABLE2 T2 
     ON T1.COLUMN3 = T2.COLUMN3
ORDER BY T1.COLUMN1;
```

(If I had to guess, there is an index on `TABLE1(COLUMN1, COLUMN3)` that can be used for both the `JOIN` and the `ORDER BY`, but the Oracle optimizer might choose another execution path without the `ORDER BY`.)

What can you do?  First, you can try recompiling the view.  The execution plan may not be optimal if the underlying data has changed.  Second, you can insert hints into the query to force a particular plan.

Comment: Are you sure about that? (that the execution plan for the _view_ is already set when the view is _created_)?

Comment: I just posted the execution plans. The only difference I see is that the view is inbetween the sort and filter, but dont know how you would get around that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I thought I was vague "the execution plan is created when the query is compiled".  I didn't say "when it is created" -- I actually don't now when Oracle compiles views, but I do know that it does and the execution plan is then sticky until the view is re-compiled.  The documentation could be a little clearer on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to select data from huge volume tables with lots of join condition, It is advisable to use WITH clause. It definitely reduces the overload of ordering the DIRECT query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW MY_VIEW        
AS                                          
WITH TEMP_AV AS                             
  (SELECT T1.COLUMN1,                       
    T2.COLUMN 2                             
  FROM TABLE1 T1,                           
    TABLE2 T2                               
  WHERE T1.COLUMN3=T2.COLUMN3               
  )                                         
SELECT * FROM TEMP_AV A ORDER BY A.COLUMN1;
```

Comment: I already use a WITH inside the view, which itself already saved me a lot of execution time. The problem still remains on the ORDER BY.

Answer (score -2):

In order for you to Order By the view it needs to return everything then order it and doesnt have access to the indexing.

Using Order By in the direct select can make use of the indexing directly.

Suggestion. Put the Order By into your view.

Comment: Can an `Order By` be applied to a view in Oracle?

Comment: @christiandev I dont know for certain but i suppose so.

Comment: might be worth testing it http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8004.htm

Comment: I tested and it doesnt keep the order. I have also read lots of posts advising against using order by in views